# Path to image in Wordpress theme stylesheet

Tags: wordpress, path

I have an image in wp-includes/images/image-example.jpg

What's the path that I could use in my theme's CSS stylesheet to point to that image? I would like to use that image as a background image on a page.

Comment: Why is the image outside of your theme?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:-

```
$image_path = site_url() . "/wp-includes/images/image-example.jpg";
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I did it in a different way - since this image will be used as a background for this specific theme, I created "images" folder in the theme directory and pointed it as a source folder - it worked :)

Comment: That would be great, that you are using in theme.